Not able to send images using ejabberd server and conversations client
installed ejabberd latest version on ubuntu desktop. using conversations as android client but failed to send images.
done modification in ejabberd.yml as per official docs but not worked so far. need ymal configuration by which files or images could be shared between conversations clients
